# Php connect error between to file

Tags: php, html

This is my `bagıs.php` file which is connected with `bagısyap.php` file.

```
  <? php
  if (loggedin()) {
    require 'bagısyap.php';

    include 'connect.inc.php';
    include 'core.inc.php';
    include 'bagısyap.php';
    if (isset($_POST['esyaara2']) && isset($_POST['il']) && isset($_POST['adet'])) {
      $esyaadi = $_POST['esyaara2'];
      $il = $_POST['il'];
      $adet = $_POST['adet'];
      if (!empty($esyaadi) && !empty($il) && !empty($adet)) {
        echo 'OK';
      } else {
        echo 'alanların hepsini doldurunuz!';
      }

    } ?>
```

This file below is `bagısyap.php` file which contains form for `bagıs.php`
I want to get forms data from `bagıs.php` but I can not get it

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
<html>

<body>
  <div style="background:white;height:320px; width:660px;margin-left:16%;margin-top:1%">
    <p>deneme 1.3.1</p>
    <h3 style="padding:0px 0px 0px 200px"><strong><ins>Bağış Yap</ins></strong></h3>
    <p stye="padding:0px 0px 0px 250px">Fazla eşyalarınızı ihtiyaç sahiplerine gönderebilir ; yada ihtiyacınız olan eşyaları isteyebilirsiniz</p>
    <form action="bagıs.php" method="POST" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 200px">
      <br>
      <select name="cars">
        <option value="giysi">Giysi</option>
        <option value="ayakkabı">Ayakkabı</option>
        <option value="caır">Çadır</option>
        <option value="hırdavat">Hırdavat</option>
        <option value="diger">Diğer</option>
      </select>
      <br>Eşya yazınız
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="esyaara2" placeholder="Eşya yazınız"></input>
      <br>Şehir Giriniz
      <br>

      <input type="text" name="il" placeholder="Şehir Giriniz"></input>
      <br>Adet
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="adet" placeholder="Adet"></input>
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" name="kayıt" value="Kayıt"></input>
      <br>
      <br>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What problems are you having? Why can't you get it?

Comment: i cant get the form's value from bagısyap.php .

Comment: I understand that, but are you getting an error? Where exactly are you stuck and what have you tried?

Comment: i have bagısyap.php which contains form for getting value for database but this file is not main file . main file bagıs.php and one of its division contains  bagısyap.php by 'require bagısyap.php' . but when i try to write value in form and press ok i cant get echos .

Answer (score 0):

I changed te bagısyap.php (form action)

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/><html>
<body>


<div style="background:white;height:320px; width:660px;margin-left:16%;margin-top:1%">
    <p>deneme 1.3.1</p>
    <h3 style="padding:0px 0px 0px 200px"><strong><ins>Bağış Yap</ins></strong></h3>
    <p stye="padding:0px 0px 0px 250px">
Fazla eşyalarınızı ihtiyaç sahiplerine gönderebilir ; yada ihtiyacınız olan eşyaları isteyebilirsiniz</p>
    <form action="<?php function isempty(){if(isset($_POST['esyaara2'])&&isset($_POST['il'])&&isset($_POST['adet'])){return true;}else{return false;}}?>"  method="POST" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 200px"><br><select name="cars">
<option value="giysi">Giysi</option>
<option value="ayakkabı">Ayakkabı</option>
<option value="caır">Çadır</option>
<option value="hırdavat">Hırdavat</option>
<option value="diger">Diğer</option>
</select><br>Eşya yazınız<br>
                <input type="text" name="esyaara2" placeholder="Eşya yazınız"></input><br>Şehir Giriniz<br>


<input type="text" name="il" placeholder="Şehir Giriniz"></input><br>Adet<br>
<input type="text" name="adet" placeholder="Adet"></input><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="kayıt" value="Kayıt"></input><br><br>
        </form>
        <?php if(isempty()){
                    $esyaadi=$_POST['esyaara2'];
                    $il=$_POST['il'];
                    $adet=$_POST['adet'];
                    if(!empty($esyaadi)&&!empty($il)&&!empty($adet)){
                    require 'connect.inc.php';  
                            if(loggedin()){
                            $userid=getusersfield('id');
                            }
        $query="INSERT INTO `esya_bagis` VALUES ('', ".mysql_real_escape_string($esyaadi)." , 'giyim' , ".mysql_real_escape_string($adet)." , ".mysql_real_escape_string($il)." , $userid)";
                        if($query_run=mysql_query($query)){
                            header("Location: bagısregister.php");      
                        }else{
                            echo mysql_error();
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                    echo 'alanların hepsini doldurunuz!';
                    }

                }?>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

and i can get values from form.